# How to loop through arrays in React?

Tags: reactjs

How to loop through arrays of objects in reactjs using map function?

```
shop: [
{id: 35, name: 'jumper', color: 'red', price: 20},
{id: 42, name: 'shirt', color: 'blue', price: 15},
{id: 56, name: 'pants', color: 'green', price: 25},
{id: 71, name: 'socks', color: 'black', price: 5},
{id: 72, name: 'socks', color: 'white', price: 5},]

<ul><li>[array loop]</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
  {shop.map((item, index) => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>}
</ul>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

> **Have you used the map function before?**

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
So the map function was introduced to Javascript in ES2015. It greatly simplifies the looping process and cuts out the need to use a simply for loop or a forEach function.

```
<ul>
    {shop.map((item, key) =><li item={item} key={item.id}></li>)}
</ul>
```

Comment: why are you replying to your own question.